# Amazon S3 .net sdk using IAM credentials

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I want to use Amazon .net sdk to upload files to one of my organization's S3 buckets. All of the organization's employees have been provided with an AWS Identity & Access Management (IAM) username & password. When i installed AWS .NET SDK and tried to run the sample application it required Access Key ID and the secret key (which i dont know). Is there an option to use my IAM user name and password to develop similar application or any other option which does not require the use of Access Key ID and the secret key. Please help.
Also any help (kind of tutorial) AWS .NET SDK is much appreciated as i am completely new to this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Access and Secret Key are tied to the Amazon S3 account.Tutorial on .NET SDK is on the following link. http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/ The code samples are pretty good and self explanatory.

Comment: I had to upvote this because it's the answer.  The IAMs have a key and secret key tied to them.